# Implementation method not being called from Rest Controller using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to call an implementation method from my controller class. I've annotated the interface with @Component and Autowired this interface in my controller. But, its throwing me 404 exception.

On another way, I created a simple DAO and annotated with @Component, this is working from my controller.

My question is I want to follow by calling an interface method, which inturn will call the DAO.

Here is my flow.

```
@RestController
public class PurchaseController {

/*@Autowired
private DpDAO dpDAO;*/  ----> This is working
@Autowired
private PurchaseService purchaseService; --> This is not working

@GetMapping("/purchase/{partyId}/{dealId}")
public String createPurchase(@PathVariable("partyId") String partyId, @PathVariable("transactionId") String transactionId) {
    return purchaseService.createPurchase(partyId, transactionId); --> This is not working
    //return dpDAO.createPurchase(partyId, transactionId); --> This is working
}
}
```

My interface

```
@Component
public interface PurchaseService {
    public String createPurchase(String partyId, String transactionId);
}
```

DpDAO  class

```
@Component
public class DpDAO  {

public String createPurchase(String partyId, String dealId) {
    // Able to get logs here
    return null;
}

}
```

Cannot we annotate the interfaces? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that `PurchaseService` is an interface, while `DpDAO` is a class. That is, you have an instance of the latter but not of the former.

If that's true, then Spring cannot find a bean to inject. So you'll need some way of creating an instance of `PurchaseService` to be injected.

You could create an instance thus:

```
@Component
class PurchaseServiceImpl implements PurchaseService
{
     // Fill in
}
```

Or you have a factory method on one of your initialiser classes. Something like:

```
@Bean
public PurchaseService createService()
{
     return new PurchaseServiceImpl();
}
```

Comment: Exactly, its an interface. How can I acheive this

Comment: I followed the first way. But how to inject this Impl class in my controller?

Comment: Can I directly inject my Interface as it is or should I do any changes

Comment: Hmmm, it should have been injected in the same was as DpDAO. Did you include `@Component` and is the package that it's in on the path to be inspected by Spring for components?

Answer (score 0):

Your interfaces is a specification. Although you annotate with @Autowired your Interface what spring really does is injecting the implementation you specified.

Thus 
either you provide an interface implementation as a component

```
@Service
public class PurchaseServiceImpl implements PurchaseService {

}
```

Or you create a bean that gives back the implementation of your choice

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public PurchaseService purchaseService() {
       //TODO
    }
}
```

There are case of multiple interface implementations. In those cases you use the qualifier. For example

```
@Service("one")
public class PurchaseServiceIOne implements PurchaseService {

}


@Service("two")
public class PurchaseServiceTwo implements PurchaseService {

}
```

The you inject the service using the qualifier

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("one")
private PurchaseService purchaseService;
```